# 14 essays are prescribed. What is the minimum number of essays to study such that at least one will be in the 3 that are on the exam?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If 14 essay topics are prescribed, and 3 essay topics are given from those 14 on an exam, and one must choose 1 essay topic from that 3 to write about, what is the minimum amount of topics one could study such that at least one essay topic they have studied will be on the exam?

Comment: Could you articulate what you mean in "your question", @zebra ? (and re: your question, why is it even a question?)

Comment: The OP could have been a fine question, if the asker included more context, @gebra.  If you are referring in any way to the level of math needed, your comment is entirely inappropriate.  MSE welcomes well thought out questions, at all levels of math,  when the asker includes additional information, his/her work, his/her attempts or specific questions where s/he is stuck...etc.

Answer (score 2):

12 - for obvious reasons. (Otherwise you didn't touch 3 topics and exactly those may be chosen.)

Comment: @amWhy I did. See above.

Comment: Hmmm. Could have fooled me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a total of $14$ number of essay topics for the exam. The worst case can be:  None of the essays you read come up in the exam, (this is possible in the case you read/study $11$ or fewer essays.

By reading a $12th$ essay, you will ensure you have read, such that you will have read  at least one that is on the exam.

Comment: Dear @Vidyanshu,  I hope you don't mind my edit.  You logic and answer were/are fine;  I was simply trying to fix a tense, and help express your answer a bit more smoothly.  You are free to roll-back the edit, to return to your original post. (Or ask me to do that, and I'll surely do so.)

Comment: No way @amwhy..